# Disabling Headers on Specific URLs

Tags: java, spring-security

Fairly new to Spring, so this may be basic.
We've recently transitioned from Spring 3 to 4 and running into some header issues with the new [defaults](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#default-security-headers) tied to one of our partners business logic

We would like to keep the defaults everywhere except for a specific URL "/stg/strategem/strg/drammin.syg"

Currently we have:

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="web.AuthenticaionEntryPoint">
   <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_ADMIN', 'GKR_ADMIN_ADV')"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_USER')"/>
</http>
```

How can I configure this so that ["/stg/strategem/strg/drammin.syg"] is still secured but is the only place where the below header configuration applies?

```
<headers defaults-disabled="true">
    <content-type-options />
    <hsts include-subdomains="true" max-age-seconds="31536000"/>
    <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    <xss-protection block="false"/>
</headers>
```

UPDATE 1: Was able to make the URL I need headerless more specific

UPDATE 2:
I just tried adding another http block, but I keep getting the Spring Error

> A universal match pattern ('/**')
>   is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored.

Regardless of what order I put these blocks in, I've even tried removing the "/**" pattern, this error still comes up.

My attempt:

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="web.AuthenticaionEntryPoint">
   <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_ADMIN', 'GKR_ADMIN_ADV')"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_USER')"/>
</http>

<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="web.AuthenticaionEntryPoint">       
    <headers defaults-disabled="true">
        <content-type-options />
        <hsts include-subdomains="true" max-age-seconds="31536000"/>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <xss-protection block="false"/>
    </headers>

    <intercept-url pattern="/stg/strategem/strg/drammin.syg" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_ADMIN', 'GKR_ADMIN_ADV', 'GKR_USER')"/>
</http>
```

UPDATE 3: Was able to find a solution, check it out in the Answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright folks, I was able to get this working by using a separate HTTP block that had a pattern, but no intercept URL. Trying to make both have security configurations was what caused the issue.

Thanks Zilvinas for pointing me down the right path.

The first block applies header configs to just the specific url. Everything else gets Spring's defaults.
The second block applies security measures. (including to the specific url since I have a /** wildcard)

```
<http pattern="/stg/strategem/strg/drammin.syg">       
    <headers defaults-disabled="true">
        <content-type-options />
        <hsts include-subdomains="true" max-age-seconds="31536000"/>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <xss-protection block="false"/>
    </headers>
</http>

<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="web.AuthenticaionEntryPoint">
   <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_ADMIN', 'GKR_ADMIN_ADV')"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access = "hasAnyRole('GKR_USER')"/>
</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have multiple `<http>` blocks with different configuration for each. See [Spring Security Reference - Multiple Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)

Comment: Morning Zilvinas, thanks for reaching out.

I just tried adding another http block, but I keep getting the Spring Error
"A universal match pattern ('/**')
is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored."

Regardless of what order I put these blocks in, I've even tried removing the "/**" pattern, this error still comes up. 

I've added my attempts to the main question

Comment: But you said that you need different logic for a different URL pattern. Use *that* pattern first, and then `/**` later

Comment: I tried that ordering, but it still complained about /** 
Looks like it was tied to me trying to declare security on the same thing twice.

Pointing out multiple HTTP blocks helped a lot and led me down to path to what ended up working. Thanks for the assist!